# i am having tableviewcontroller and viewcontroller with pickerview,when i am clicking the rows in tablevc the same detail viewcontroller is opening

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller

when i navigating one row to viewcontroller which having picker view.it is navigating there i am adding sections.when i go back to tableviewcontroller and click another row it is navigating but the section is displaying which i have added in first row.i dont want that sections in section row.can u please suggest what i have to change inorder to rectify that problem.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   // Return the number of rows in the section.
  return self.semesteryear.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Semester * semester=self.semesteryear[indexPath.row];
   cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",semester.semesterName,semester.semesterYear];

  return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"newsemester"]){
      semesterselectionVC * newsem=[segue destinationViewController];
     newsem.tableViewController=self;
   }
   else
   {
        int selectedrow =[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;
        EditSectionVC* editsectionvc=[segue destinationViewController];
        editsectionvc.semester=self.semesteryear[selectedrow]; 
        editsectionvc.semester=self.semesteryear[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
        editsectionvc.navigationItem.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",editsectionvc.semester.semesterName,editsectionvc.semester.semesterYear];
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the issue is in the tableview delegate code.  Please update your question which that code.

Comment: i have added delegate methods .

Comment: Please learn to format your question; I have edited your question once but I will not continue to do so.

Comment: first i have added in that format it is not posting .so i remove spaces .

Comment: Read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: this is first time i am posting thank u so much for guiding .can u please solve my question

Answer (score 0):

I think each time you are navigating and coming back your data is save in array `semesteryear`.Remove the contents from array when you come back to this screen.One way to do that is remove the old contents before adding the new ones from `semesteryear` `[self.semesteryear removeAllObjects]` and than add new ones want to display.